# I think edit array value like set("a.b.c.d.e", "my new value") but dont work

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

i want edit a value of key like `$class->set("this.is.a.children.key", "and this is my value")`.

My function:

```
public function set ($key, $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->config)) {
        $this->config[$key] = $value;
        return true;
    } else {
        if(strpos($key, ".")){
            $keys = explode(".", $key);
            if (count($keys) > 0) {
                if (array_key_exists($keys[0], $this->config)) {
                    function rv($source, $array_keys, $value){
                        if (count($array_keys) == 1) {
                            $source[$array_keys[0]] = $value;
                        } else {
                            return rv(
                                $source[$array_keys[0]],
                                array_slice($array_keys, 1),
                                $value
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    $this->config = rv($this->config, $keys, $value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My Array:

```
$this->config = array(
    "a"=>array(
        "b"=>1,
        "c"=>array(
            "d"=>array(
                "e"=>2,
                "f"=>"x",
                "g"=>null,
            )
        ),
        "h"=>null,
        "i"=>102.2,
        "j"=>array(
            3=>3
        )
    ),
    "k"=>":)"
);
```

And my sentence:

```
$this->set("k", "This is K");
$this->set("a.c.d.g", "This is a -> c -> d -> g");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are modifying the `$source` array within the `rv` method, you'll have to make it a reference. For the same reason, you should also remove the `$this->config = ...` assignment.

```
class Foo
{
    public $config = array(
        "a" => array(
            "b" => 1,
            "c" => array(
                "d" => array(
                    "e" => 2,
                    "f" => "x",
                    "g" => null,
                )
            ),
            "h" => null,
            "i" => 102.2,
            "j" => array(
                3 => 3
            )
        ),
        "k" => ":)"
    );

    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->config)) {
            $this->config[$key] = $value;
            return true;
        } else {
            if (strpos($key, ".")) {
                $keys = explode(".", $key);
                if (count($keys) > 0) {
                    if (array_key_exists($keys[0], $this->config)) {
                        // Added & to $source here
                        function rv(&$source, $array_keys, $value)
                        {
                            if (count($array_keys) == 1) {
                                $source[$array_keys[0]] = $value;
                            } else {
                                // No need for return statement
                                rv(
                                    $source[$array_keys[0]],
                                    array_slice($array_keys, 1),
                                    $value
                                );
                            }
                        }

                        // No assignment
                        rv($this->config, $keys, $value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        $this->set("k", "This is K");
        $this->set("a.c.d.g", "This is a -> c -> d -> g");
        print_r($this->config);
    }
}

(new Foo())->test();
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => 1
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [d] => Array
                        (
                            [e] => 2
                            [f] => x
                            [g] => This is a -> c -> d -> g
                        )

                )

            [h] => 
            [i] => 102.2
            [j] => Array
                (
                    [3] => 3
                )

        )

    [k] => This is K
)
```

Comment: That's strange. Works for me with PHP 5.5.20. Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the file, if you have not already done that, to see if you get any error message.